# Salesforce Public Calendars query

Tags: apex, event, calendar

I want to add event to public Calendars using Apex code in trigger. Currently I have hardcoded id of public  Calendar in my code. But I don't want to hardcode id of Calendars. I want to query it in my code. But I am not able to query it as it says **sObject type 'Calendar' is not supported.**

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Ankush

Comment: Can anyone please suggest me how to query salesforce Calendar object

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this as well. I am having trouble finding a link to post (I will keep searching), but our workaround is a custom object with a `Calendar_Id__c` field because we need lookups to this object, otherwise you could use a custom setting to store the names.

Inelegant, perhaps, but you can retrieve them programmatically as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it finally in API Version 45 - `Select Id,Name From Calendar Where Type='Resource'`

Comment: SELECT Id, Name, type FROM Calendar WHERE type = 'Public'

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read and tried, this is currently not possible. Sad, but that's how it is.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some links to what you have read saying this is not possible.