# How do you create Resource Calendar in Apex for test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, calendar

I need to have a Resource Calendar in Apex test class. I tried to do below in Test Class.

```
    List<Calendar>  lc = new List<Calendar>();

    for(Account acc :listAcc)
        Calendar c = new Calendar(Name = acc.Name, isActive = true, Type = 'Resource');
```

and it throws below,

[image]

[It seems it's not a creatable SObject according to doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_calendar.htm).

Any helpful thoughts, ideas to do test coverage/asserts in a managed package? 
Thanks!

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/51641/2995

Comment: have you considered using a selector pattern for querying `Calendar` in the code-under-test and then mocking the selector's return `Calendar[]` in the testmethod by using json.deserialize technique.  An [apexMocks solution for this can be found here](http://cropredysfdc.com/2017/10/23/apexmocks-selectors-and-formula-fields/) but you there are alternatives by using [interfaces and dependency injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/07/breaking-runtime-dependencies-with-dependency-injection.html).